# Linked List, 'int' object has no atrribute '_____'

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm currently testing out my Linked List's functions, as of now I'm trying to do my getCount and getIndex functions. Every time I try to test it I get this error.

```
C:\Python33\python.exe "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter4/Test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
1
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter4/Test.py", line 28, in <module>
2
    print(LinkedList.getCount(node1,101))
3
3
  File "C:\Users\koopt_000\Desktop\College\Sophomore Semester 2\Computer Science 231\Chapter4\LinkedList.py", line 152, in getCount
2
    if current.item == value:
1
3
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'item'
1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I thought that my 'node 1' be considered an int object. Here is my code for the getCount and getIndex.

```
def getCount(self, value):

        ''' This function counts the amount of times a certain item is in the Linked List.'''

        count = 0
        current = self.item
        while current is not None:
            if current.item == value:
                count += 1
            current = current.link

        return count

#--------------------------------------------------------------

    def getIndex(self, value):

        ''' getIndex finds the index of the selected item and returns that value. '''

        count = 0
        current = self.head

        while current is not None:
            if current.item == value:
                count += 1
            current = current.link

        return current.item1
```

And here is my code where I am testing the getCount and getIndex functions.

```
from ListNode import ListNode
from LinkedList import LinkedList

node1 = ListNode(1)
node2 = ListNode(2)
node3 = ListNode(3)

node1.link = node2
node2.link = node3

def print_list(node):
    while node:
        print(node,)
        node = node.link
    print

def print_backward(list):
    if list == None: return
    head = list
    tail = list.link
    print_backward(tail)
    print(head,)

print_list(node1)
print_backward(node1)
print(LinkedList.__max__(node1))
print(LinkedList.__min__(node1))
print(LinkedList.getCount(node1,2))
```

Maybe I am using the getCount function wrong but Is there anyway I change my getCount function and my getIndex function so it does what it is supposed to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line of yours:

```
LinkedList.getCount(node1,2)
```

suggets that you are calling getCount as a class method, not an instance method. However, you define getCount as an instance method:

```
def getCount(self, value)
```

This can be demonstrated on this example:

```
class A:

    def getCount(self, value):
        print(self, value)


print(A.getCount(1,2)) # prints 1,2. So instead of self, you have 1.
```

So in your case self is treated as node1. This is counter intuitive, as self should refer to the current instance of an object. Meybe this is part of the problem. Really difficult to say much more with the code snippets you provided.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quit understand. When I do that, it just prints '1,2'. I thought my code would find how many times a certain item appears in the list.

Comment: The point i was trying to make is that `self` should point to the current instance. Like `this` in c++. In your code self is not self, its node1. You havent provided code for `ListNode` nor `LinkedList` so difficult to say how they behave if you use something else than actual `self`.